# Data Binding Compiler cannot find custom binding adapter provided

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have made a binding adapter available statically inside my `Fragment` which basically change my button appearance from "Stop" to "Play" and vice-versa.

```
companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("playState")
        fun Button.setPlayState(item: UIState) {
            item.let {
                if (it.isPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop")
                    setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorStop))
                } else {
                    setText("Play")
                    setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPlay))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my layout file. I have provided a data class for it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <!-- stuff here -->
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.mypackage.ui.ViewModel"/>
        <variable
            name="uistate"
            type="com.mypackage.ui.UIState" />
    </data>
    <!-- layout, buttons, and more stuff here. Just pay attention to this following button -->
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:layout_height="75sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.onPlayClicked()}"
            android:text="@string/play_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minus_layout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.026"
            app:playState="@{uistate}"/>


</layout>
```

`UIState` itself is pretty self-explanatory.

```
data class UIState(var isPlaying: Boolean)
```

and the `() -> viewmodel.onPlayClicked()` flips the `Boolean` at `UIState`.

After compiling, Data Binding Compiler throws this error:

```
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.Button app:playState> 
that accepts parameter type 'com.mypackage.ui.UIState'
```

**I have tried:**

1. Rebuilding the project by removing .gradle folder
2. Looking for answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799087/two-way-binding-cannot-resolve-a-setter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706399/how-to-use-data-binding-with-fragment/53932633#53932633).
3. Removed `@JvmStatic` annotation at the extension function
4. Moved the extension function to top level instead of `Fragment`'s companion object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to add kotlin plugin in your gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `@JvmStatic` because you are using Kotlin extension feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the view reference as a paramater to your BindingAdapter method.

```
 @BindingAdapter("playState")
    fun setPlayState(button:Button,item: UIState) {
        //do your work here
    }
```

Comment: This is same as what he used. He just used Extension function way. What is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

Your namespace

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

is wrong for custom binding adapters. Please use the namespace

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

since `app:playState` is not in the namespace you have given its not working properly

Comment: i have used "http://schemas.android.com/tools" at `tools` namespace. I have tried your solution as well but no change.